# Have devas ever been captured on camera?

Tags: buddhist-cosmology, deva

Are there any instances of people unwillingly capturing photographic evidence of devas/angels? Could the UFO sightings or encounters have been angels or devas(specifically terrestrial devas) all along? Can some one please shed some light on this?

Comment: I closed this question as opinion-based, but if you or others disagree that this question is opinion-based and can justify that view, it can be reopened.